# Call functions from fellow child classes in C++

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

I have a parent class Piece that has several child classes including Queen, Rook and Bishop. However, a Queen can move like a Rook and a Bishop combined so it is conceptually the fusion of the two. I want to call functions from the Rook and Bishop class in the Queen class. I have tried making Queen inherit from both Rook and Bishop instead of inheriting from Piece however, then it inherits two copies of attributes from Piece (one in Bishop and one in Rook) which means I can't refer to either.

Is there a way to do this or do I just have to rewrite the functions for Queen?

EDIT:
Sorry, I think my question is a bit hard to understand with just words. Since this is for university, I am unable to provide code as that may be against their plagiarism policies but here are the header files for each class.

I basically want to call the `canMoveTo` and `squaresInBetween` functions of Bishop and Rook from Queen since Bishop can move diagonally, Rook can move horizontally and vertically, and Queen can move diagonally, horizontally and vertically.

Piece.h

```
#ifndef PIECE_H
#define PIECE_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Piece // abstract
{
public:
    Piece(string currentPos); // constructor - sets currentposition
    virtual bool canMoveTo(string square) = 0; // able to move to that square on an empty board (movement rules)
    virtual vector<string> squaresInBetween(string square) = 0; // squares in between current position and square (including square)
    virtual ~Piece(); // virtual destructor to call correct destructor for each piece
    string getPosition();

protected:
    string currentPosition; // board coordinates (e.g. "d4") // change to char [2] later?

private:
    friend class Player;
    void setPosition(string pos);
};

#endif
```

Rook.h

```
#ifndef ROOK_H
#define ROOK_H

#include "Piece.h"

class Rook : public Piece
{
public:
    Rook(string currentPos);
    virtual bool canMoveTo(string square);
    virtual vector<string> squaresInBetween(string square);
};

#endif
```

Bishop.h

```
#ifndef BISHOP_H
#define BISHOP_H

#include "Piece.h"

class Bishop : public Piece
{
public:
    Bishop(string currentPos);
    virtual bool canMoveTo(string square);
    virtual vector<string> squaresInBetween(string square);
};

#endif
```

Queen.h

```
#ifndef QUEEN_H
#define QUEEN_H

#include "Piece.h"

class Queen : public Piece
{
public:
    Queen(string currentPos);
    virtual bool canMoveTo(string square);
    virtual vector<string> squaresInBetween(string square);
};

#endif
```

Comment: there is a virtual `move()` method? Its not quite clear what you want to gain by inherting. A queen is not a rook nor a bishop.

Comment: Don't try to solve everything with inheritance. Multiple inheritance is in my opinion a sign you didn't complete your decomposition. Think of it like this, a Piece has one or more moves it can make. Then you can model moves as a seperate class and then you can let the Rook aggregate one kind of move, a Bishop another kind of move.. and the Queen aggregates two kinds of moves. Summary : **OO is not inheritance**

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Hi, sorry for the inconvenience. I've provided the class headers in the edit to the question. A queen is not a rook nor a bishop but it can move like both a bishop (diagonally) and a rook (horizontally and vertically) hence, it would be useful to call functions from Bishop and Rook in Queen to avoid code repetition.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I don't quite understand what this Moves class would enclose. I basically need to check if the piece can move from its current position to another square in each piece. I think you may have misinterpreted the question, I've edited it to clarify it. Would this Moves class enclose the `canMoveTo` functions that I have in each piece class?

Comment: No I understood you, but multiple inheritance is still not a good idea to do code reuse.
Just let a Queen move like a Queen, not a combination of Rook and Bishop.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are dead set on an OOP solution -- i.e. a solution involving inheritance -- you could use "mix-in" type classes `MovesLikeRook` and `MovesLikeBishop` and then make Rook and Bishop inherit from the appropriate class and have Queen inherit from both.

But as others have said, you don't need to solve every program with OOP. In this case if you don't want to write the same rook move and bishop move code multiple times you can just put that logic in free or static functions that can be called by Rook, Bishop, and Queen. I mean, that is one idea. But there are lots of ways to not repeat yourself and also not use a complicated object hierarchy, which is generally seen as a good thing in modern programming.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried making Queen inherit from both Rook and Bishop instead
> of inheriting from Piece however, then it inherits two copies of
> attributes from Piece (one in Bishop and one in Rook) which means I
> can't refer to either.

This case is known as *diamond* inheritance. C++ has a way of solving the problem of "two copies of attributes from Piece": virtual inheritance. It will look like:

```
class Piece {/*...*/};
class Rook : virtual public Piece {/*...*/};
class Bishop : virtual public Piece {/*...*/};
class Queen : public Rook, public Bishop {/*...*/};
```

This might work for you, this is rarely a good design.

Comment: I've added some more code in the question. In what situations might this be a bad design? From the code in the question, do you think there may be issues with this solution? Or should this be fine in this case?

Comment: I just wanted to show you the C++ mechanism to overcome your specific problem. But public inheritance is supposed to be "is-a" relationship. Do you think "Queen is a Rook" from your program's point of view? For example, if you have a function with `Rook&` argument, do you want to be able to pass `Queen`  object to it? More generally, public inheritance should not be driven by shared implementation.

Comment: I see. No, I wouldn't want to be able to pass a `Queen` object for a function with a `Rook&` argument. That would certainly be an issue. Although I do not have such functions, I probably should find another way to solve this issue. Or, I could just keep it as it is if it isn't possible. Thank you for your answer. I looked more into virtual inheritance and found [link](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html). Under "Delegating to a sister class" I found something similar to what I wanted. However, it makes the classes delegating abstract which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would check moves without virtual canMoveTo and or multiple inheritance:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// A move is described as steps a piece can make
// all moves only have to desribe the move to top-right as one step
// range will describe the range of a piece in one turn.
// moves will be combined with directions to cover all allowed moves in a turn

struct Move
{
    Move(const int x, const int y, const int r) :
        x_step{ x },
        y_step{ y },
        range{ r }
    {
    }

    int x_step;
    int y_step;
    int range;
};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// struct to contain directions of a move in a turn

struct Direction
{
    int x_direction;
    int y_direction;
};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Piece
{
public:
    explicit Piece(const std::string& start_position, std::vector<Move>&& moves) :
        m_position{ start_position },
        m_moves{ moves }
    {
    };

    // no need to make this virtual a piece will have all the information it needs
    // without inheritance
    bool can_move_to(const std::string& position)
    {
        // use vector of allowed moves
        for (const auto& direction : m_directions)
        {
            for (const auto& move : m_moves)
            {
                for (int range = 0; range < move.range; ++range)
                {
                    // calculate if piece can reach position using 
                    // the step sizes from the piece, direction and range
                    std::string calculated_position;
                    // ... todo calculation here
                    if (calculated_position == position) return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

protected:
    Piece() = default;
    virtual ~Piece() = default;
    Piece(const Piece&) = delete;
    Piece& operator=(const Piece&) = delete;
    Piece(Piece&&) = delete;

private:
    std::string m_position;
    std::vector<Move> m_moves;
    static std::vector<Direction> m_directions;
};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// all information needed to check all directions in which a piece can move

std::vector<Direction> Piece::m_directions{ {1,1},{-1,1},{1,-1},{-1,-1} };

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Rook :
    public Piece
{
public:
    explicit Rook(const std::string& position) :
        Piece(position, {{1,0,8}, {0,1,8}}) // a rook can move one horizontal, or one vertical up to a range of 8 (board size)
    {
    }
};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Bishop :
    public Piece
{
public:
    explicit Bishop(const std::string& position) :
        Piece(position, {{1,1,8}}) // a rook can move diagonally,up to a range of 8 (board size)
    {
    }
};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Knight :
    public Piece
{
public:
    explicit Knight(const std::string& position) :
        Piece(position, { {1,2,1}, {2,1,1} }) // a knight can move 1 horizontally and 2 vertically, or 2 horizontally and 1 vertically
    {
    }
};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Queen :
    public Piece
{
public:
    explicit Queen(const std::string& position) :
        Piece(position, { {1,0,8}, {0,1,8}, {1,1,8} })  // a queen can move horizontally, vertically and diagonally up to a range of 8
                                                        // IMO the extra complexity of multiple inheritance or looking up this information
                                                        // in Rook & Bishop is not worth the extra code.
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    Queen queen{ "e7" };
    auto can_move = queen.can_move_to("a1");
}
```